# How can I make a gameObject "stick" to another gameObject after it has collided with it?

Tags: c#, unity

How can I make a gameObject "stick" to another gameObject after it has collided with it? Right now the gameObject just passes through! [C#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you could have easily found this with a search. It has been asked many times before and is a pretty simple thing to do. You will usually not get many good answers (or any at all) if you dont search some first =-)

However, with that said:

IIRC, if both of your game objects have colliders attached to them and you catch that collision, you can use:

```
object1.transform.parent = object2.transform
```

Your collison code would look something like the following (I havent tested this and havent used unity in a while so it may be off a little)

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    collision.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
}
```

What the above does is takes the collided object and sets its transform to your current object. That way when your current object moves, the other one should follow along. You may get unexpected results if you have a rigid body attached to these objects too, but from what it sounds like, you dont

Comment: What do you mean by "and you catch that collision"?

Comment: This should help explain https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/on-collision-enter

Comment: This code is a bit unsafe though, parenting colliders can cause weird results, like random teleporting or object starting to move and rotate insanely, etc.

Comment: he can disable one of the colliders after he attached them