# How can I attach a ball to something?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm using Unity 2017 and am writing a game wherein you shoot a ball, and when said ball hit something (a cube for example), I want it to remain in that position that it hit.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
ball.transform.localPosition = gameObject.transform.localPosition;
```

Something like this picture :
[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what type of behaviour you want your ball to have? Currently the code "ball.transform.localPosition = gameObject.transform.localPosition;" just sets the ball's position to a gameObject one. It doesn't register anything, it just does that.

Comment: [This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110330/make-gameobject-stick-to-another-gameobject-after-it-has-collided-with-it) is also related.

Answer (score 0):

```
ball.transform.parent = gameObject.transform
```

Rotation should look something like this:

```
ball.transform.localPosition.x = sin(time * speed) * distance;
ball.transform.localPosition.y = cos(time * speed) * distance;
```